# Exploring how adjusting the input variables influence the target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, optimization, interpretation

I've seen something like this in many "prescriptive analytics" software (one example [here](https://datastories.com/learn/case-potato-baking/)): [image]

Basically a supervised ML model has been trained to predict a KPI (target variable). After training, one can explore (with a slider) how adjusting values from each individual feature may influence the output.

There is also a related "optimiser" page, where input constraints can be set to maximize/minimise some KPI of interest: [image]

I would like to know what is happening under the hood, but obviously these softwares are not open-source (I do not need to know exactly what approaches are used in this particular example, but how would develop something similar with open-source alternatives).

Specifically:

- how can one explore how adjusting the inputs would influence the outputs (link to Python code / library would help)? I am very familiar with scikit-learn, but have not seen anything of the like there?
- a recommended open-source optimiser that could perform such optimisation given a set of constraints (I doubt that state-of-the-art proprietary optimisers like Gurobi are being used). See the [documentation](https://developer.datastories.com/sdk/apireference.html#module-datastories.optimization) for the software I mentioned, although it is not very transparent.

Comment: I hope my answer addresses your question about how sliders lead to predicted outcomes. The inquiry about optimization really warrants a separate posted question. Optima do not even have to exist unless the problem is constrained in some way (which might be how some software package work, but you do not have to restrict yourself to particular ranges of feature values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider settings give feature values. Send those feature values through the model the same as you would do for any other combination of feature values for which you want to know the predicted outcome.

As far as a code pipeline, the sliders come from some interactive visualization. I have explored interactive plots in `matplotlib` and `bokeh` (have some posts on my Stack Overflow profile, I think), and other libraries with various capabilities must exist. Once the interactive tool gets values from the sliders, those form the input fields of the prediction method, such as `model.predict` in `sklearn`. [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html) documentation page discusses the `predict` method for `sklearn` in particular, but any software package that does predictive modeling must have something similar.